# Position text inside of canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I have some text that I'd like to render inside of the Canvas (Unity).

My text shall appear when I collect an upgrade for my game (e.g. "Power-up"). It renders the text but it's always at the center of the screen. That's the problem. It doesn't appear at the upgrade's position.

By the way, the canvas is set to "Screen Space - Overlay". The text gets rendered near at the middle of the scene. The x- and y-values are strange (almost at zero: x is e.g. -0.42 and y is -0.79).

The reference for the font:

```
public Font myFont;
```

The method that generates the text:

```
GameObject CreateText(Transform canvas_transform, float x, float y, string text_to_print, int font_size, Color text_color) {
    GameObject UItextGO = new GameObject("Text2");
    UItextGO.transform.SetParent(canvas_transform);

    RectTransform trans = UItextGO.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    trans.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);

    Text text = UItextGO.AddComponent<Text>();
    text.text = text_to_print;
    text.fontSize = font_size;
    text.font = myFont;
    text.color = text_color;

    return UItextGO;
}
```

Comment: *"That's the problem. It doesn't appear at the upgrade's position."* But no one knows what the "upgrade's position" is.

Comment: The position of the upgrades are near zero, too (but they don't appear at the center of the scene).

Answer (score 1):

`(0,0)` is the middle of the screen.
You set text as parent of `canvas_transform` in here  `UItextGO.transform.SetParent(canvas_transform);`

It means text is now child of an object and `(0,0)` is the origin point of the parent object for text object.

And instead of this `trans.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x, y);`, Try something like this: `trans.transform.position = upgrade.transform.position;` (if `(x,y)` position are the upgrade positions for sure. No need for `upgrade.transform.position`.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint!:D I'll check this out tomorrow.